# Read a file from project folder, eclipse will but terminal wont

Tags: java, eclipse, file

I have a Folder say folder ED inside my project folder Project, when I specify in Eclipse where to find the file I write File file = new File("ED/text.txt"); eclipse will access it but when I run the program in the terminal it will throw me and exception telling me the file is not found. I found a temporary solution to this by placing two dots like ../ED/text.txt and got it to work on the terminal but wont run in eclipse. What should I do to make them work in both? Is it something with how I set the JRE and Classpath?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info .

Comment: .. means that ED is in the folder containing your current directory (i.e. the folder you'll be taken to if you "go back" 1 folder) so are you sure you're in the right directory when running your program in terminal?

Comment: I have tried running it from the terminal setting the classpath to the project folder so it includes the ED folder, but when I try to run it it will give me some symbol error. So I run it from src and when I do that it throws the exception, is there anyway that I can run the program from the project directory(includes ED, src...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should place "**ED/text.txt**" in your class path.

Eg. Place under **Java Resources/src**
[image: capture]